# Obtener el Id de un repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, id

Luego de cargar un asp:repeater con servicios deseo seleccionar uno y obtener el IdServicio del mismo para poder guardarlo en ListaDeDeseos.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="InfoServicio" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  >
         <HeaderTemplate>
          
          </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div  class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4" runat="server">
                <div class="thumbnail" style="text-align: center;" runat="server">
          
                   <div >
                       <br />
                       <br />
                       <br />
                        <div class="caption" runat="server">     

                           
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTitulo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Titulo")%> ' Font-Size="25px"></asp:Label>
                        
                            <br />
                            
                      
                          <asp:Label ID="LblIdServicio" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("IdServicio")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            <a runat="server"><img src='/Content/Image/<%# Eval("URLImagen")%>' class="img-responsive col-md-12" /></a>
                           
                          
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDescripcion" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Descripcion")%>' Font-Size="20px"></asp:Label>
                           

                      <p style="font-size:larger;">$ <asp:Label ID="lblPrecio" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Precio")%>' Font-Size="25px"></asp:Label></p>

                        </div>
                         <div class="item-toolbar">
                          
                            <Button type="button" data-target="#mdl_servicio_agregado" data-toggle="modal" runat="server" Text="Comprar"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg "   ID="BtnComprar" CommandName="Comprar"    onclick="BtnComprar_Click" >Comprar</Button>
                           
                         </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
         
            </FooterTemplate>
             
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Por detrás tengo el siguiente código donde cargo el asp:repeater... donde creó la lista de servicios y relleno el repeater

```
 List<ServicioEntidad> unServicios = new List<ServicioEntidad>();
        private UsuarioEntidad usuarioentidad = new UsuarioEntidad();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServicioBLL unServicioBLL = new ServicioBLL();
            usuarioentidad = (UsuarioEntidad)HttpContext.Current.Session["Usuario"];


            unServicios = (List<ServicioEntidad>)unServicioBLL.SelectALLServicios();
            InfoServicio.DataSource = unServicios;
            InfoServicio.DataBind();


        }
```

La dificultad me surge cuando hago click  desde el asp:repeater en uno de los servicios y quiero capturar el ID del mismo.. intente de varias maneras sin éxito.

```
 protected void BtnComprar_Click(object sends, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Current = HttpContext.Current;
            var logueadoStatic = (UsuarioEntidad)Current.Session["NomUsuario"];

            ListaDeDeseoBLL unaListaDeseosBLL = new ListaDeDeseoBLL();
            ListaDeDeseoEntidad unaListaDeseo = new ListaDeDeseoEntidad();

            int IdServ;

                // no reconoce el Index
                IdServ =((Label)InfoServicio.Items[index].FindControl("IdServicio")).Text;

               // no reconoce el FindControl
                IdServ = ((Label)InfoServicio.Items.FindControl("IdServicio")).Text;

            unaListaDeseo.NombreUsuario = logueadoStatic.Nombre;
            unaListaDeseo.NumeroDocumento = logueadoStatic.NumeroDocumento;
            unaListaDeseo.IdServicio = IdServ;
            unaListaDeseosBLL.ListaDeseosInsert(unaListaDeseo);        
        }
```

El objetivo es capturar el usuario, su documento y el ID del servicio deseado para grabarlos en la BD. Probe de varias maneras a través de label pero no lo logre. Por otro lado intente cambiando el botón a linkbutton pero no me permitiría llamar al modal (o al menos yo no se como). Otro dato que note es que en el aspx.designer.cs no figuran las etiquetas correspondientes al asp:repeater, intente actualizando el diseño, eliminando el aspx.designer.cs y generando de nuevo a ver si asi se solucionaba pero no funciono. desde ya gracias

Comment: ¿Segura que ese es el ID del control? Creo que el ID es LblIdServicio

Comment: @CarlosPozos si , tal ves lo exprese mal pero lo que pretendo es obtener el IdServicio que lo trae en la label LblIdServicio y no me sale. Nose como capturarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que se tiene que conocer el item padre del botón para poder buscar dentro de él al control Label:

```
 protected void BtnComprar_Click(object sends, EventArgs e)
 {
    var Current = HttpContext.Current;
    var logueadoStatic = (UsuarioEntidad)Current.Session["NomUsuario"];

    ListaDeDeseoBLL unaListaDeseosBLL = new ListaDeDeseoBLL();
    ListaDeDeseoEntidad unaListaDeseo = new ListaDeDeseoEntidad();

    // El detalle está en encontrar el item padre del botón que se presionó
    Button btn = (Button) sender;
    RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;
    
    // Buscamos el control en ese item 
    Label lbl = (Label)item.FindControl("LblIdServicio");
    int IdServ = (int)lbl.Text;

    unaListaDeseo.NombreUsuario = logueadoStatic.Nombre;
    unaListaDeseo.NumeroDocumento = logueadoStatic.NumeroDocumento;
    unaListaDeseo.IdServicio = IdServ;
    unaListaDeseosBLL.ListaDeseosInsert(unaListaDeseo);        
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @carlosPozos ! de esta manera pude capturar el IdServicio a través de LblIdServicio.